# Export MySQL data (Discord.js)

Tags: mysql, discord.js, bots

I'm making a bot for my Discord server but I have a problem with a test command that I have created. When I run the command I receive this text : `undefined`. And I don't know why.

My database file :

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'velocity_discord'
})

module.exports = (client) => {}

module.exports.getTicketNumber = () => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE botId = '861586919653638145'`, (err, number) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            if (number) {
                return number[0].ticketNumber
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My command code :

```js
const database = require('@features/database.js')

module.exports = {
  commands: 'testdb',
  callback: (message) => {
    const msg = `${database.getTicketNumber()}`
    message.channel.send({
      content: msg
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: If you run the SQL query, what it return ?

Comment: if I insert console log in the second if SQL return 0 (that's correct)

Comment: 0 = no row inserted. It return the amount of inserted row

Comment: Oh yes, that's the error ! How can I repair this ?

Comment: insert row in db ?

Comment: I have the same error, it return undefined in discord and 12 in console.log